# Harmonic oscillator with ladder operators - proof for sum rule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

I'm trying verify the proof of the sum rule for the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator:
$$\sum_l^\infty (E_l-E_n)\ | \langle l \ |p| \ n \rangle |^2 = \frac {mh^2w^2}{2} $$
The exercise explicitly says to use laddle operators and to express $p$ with
$$b=\sqrt{\frac {mw}{2 \hbar}}-\frac {ip}{\sqrt{2 \hbar mw}} $$
$$b^\dagger =\sqrt{\frac {mw}{2 \hbar}}+\frac {ip}{\sqrt{2 \hbar mw}} $$

For $p$ I get $$p=i \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2mw}} (b-b^\dagger) $$

To solve the exercise, we need to calculate the left side. I'm still very much a novice and am not very sure how to use the ladder operators... To start, I at least tried to expand the bra-ket:
$$\sum_l^\infty (E_l-E_n)\  \langle l \ |p| \ n \rangle \langle n \ |p| \ l \rangle  $$
and tried to insert the $p$ I solved:
$$\sum_l^\infty (E_l-E_n)\ (-\frac{\hbar}{2mw}) \langle l \ |b-b^\dagger| \ n \rangle \langle n \ |b-b^\dagger| \ l \rangle  $$
is this correct? If yes, how do I continue? The hint says to probably use $H|n\rangle=\hbar(n+\frac 12)|n\rangle$ and I know that $H|n\rangle=E|n\rangle$

Answer (score 2):

Just a tip:
$$
\sum_{l}\langle n|p|l\rangle E_l \langle l|p|n\rangle =
\langle n|pHp|n\rangle,\\
\sum_{l}\langle n|p|l\rangle \langle l|p|n\rangle =
\langle n|p^2|n\rangle,
$$
where I used the expansion of identity
$$
1 = \sum_l |l\rangle\langle l|
$$

**Update**
Perhaps more in the spirit of the exercise is to use the properties of the raising and lowering operators:
$$
b|n\rangle = \sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle,\\
b^\dagger|n\rangle = \sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle,
$$
which allows easily to calculate th matrix elements (remember that $\langle m|n\rangle = \delta_{n,m}$).

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow, how do I combine $$\sum_l^\infty (E_l-E_n)\langle l \ |p| \ n \rangle \langle n \ |p| \ l \rangle  $$ ? Would it look like this: $$ \frac 12 ( \langle n|pH-Hp|l \rangle \langle l|p|n \rangle +  \langle n|p|l \rangle \langle l|pH-Hp|n \rangle $$

Comment: I think your assignment asks that you use the creation/annihilation operators - you just need to evaluate the matrix elements in your last equation

Comment: When I evaluate the last equation in my original post, I get this: $$| \langle l|p|n \rangle |^2 = \langle n|p^2|n\rangle = \frac{h}{2mw} (2n+1) $$ is this correct? I'm kind of really lost of what to do haha. I don't know how to incorporate the sum and the hamilton operator

Comment: In your last equation you have $\langle n|b -b^\dagger|l\rangle$ - use the properties of creation and annihilation operators